# read file and save in istream c++

Tags: c++, istream

I'm fairly new to C++ and I have this assignment to verify each line of a file.

I have to create a function with only one parameter(const std::istream& p_is)

My question is How can I read a file and save the buffer to a basic istream.

I found how to output it but I can't figure our how to save it in p_is

My code so far from an example I found on here

```
    std::filebuf fb;
if (fb.open ("test.txt",std::ios::in))
  {
    std::istream File(&fb);
    while (File)
      std::cout << char(File.get());
    fb.close();
  }
```

This will output test.txt content in console perfectly

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand now what you're trying to do. You can easily copy the contents of a buffer to another `std::istream` using the overload of `operator<<()` that takes a pointer to `std::streambuf`:

```
void copy_buf(std::istream& is)
{
    if (std::ifstream in("test.txt"))
        is << in.rdbuf();                                                      /*
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                      */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`istream`, as in **input** stream. You can't write to it. You either create a second stream to an output file (`ostream`), or create an append stream in the first place.

That said, I really, really doubt you read your assignment properly, your requirements make no sense.

Comment: And as an aside, you're jumping through too many hoops just to open a file, a simple `ifstream file("test.txt");` will do it.